# How do I instantiate navigationController while passing data to viewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, instantiation

So I have a `tabBar`. Clicking a certain tab will take the user to a `viewController` which is embedded in a `navigationController`. In order to have the `navigationController` included, I instantiate the `viewController` using

```
myViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

rather than

```
myViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myID"];
```

The later code pushes the `viewController` but without the `navigationController`

This is fine up until the point I want to pass data to the instance `myViewController`. Thing is, I can't pass data with the instance referring to the initial `viewController` (which is the `navigationController`), but I can do it using an instance referring directly to `myViewController`. In other words:

This works in order to get data (but no `navigationController`):

```
viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"experienceID"];
((ExperiencesListViewController*)viewController).experiences = self.experiences;
```

and this crashes if I try to add data, but gives me a `navigationBar` if I exclude setting data:

```
viewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
((ExperiencesListViewController*)viewController).experiences = self.experiences;
```

Hope I explain this well enough. Let me know if there is something I need to clarify.

***EDIT***
My first thought was using `prepareSegue` but that doesn't seem to trigger when moving between the `tabs`. Another thought is to access `myViewController` through the instance in some way, but not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the initial `UIViewController` of that particular storyboard is a `UINavigationController`.

A simple way to get the VC that you want is getting such `UINavigationController` by calling:

```
navController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

just like you've done, and then:

```
navController.childViewControllers[0]
```

This will return the first VC of that particular navigation controller (assuming, of course, that it contains solely the VC that it's embedded in), which is probably your **ExperiencesListViewController**

Comment: Ah, really nice dude, it worked like a charm. Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot! :D Think it should be `.childViewControllers[0]` though. using just `.viewControllers[0]` didn't work for me. Might be a objective-c/swift thing, dunno.

Comment: Ohhh my bad, I posted with `Swift` in mind. Will change it - thanks for the info